# Несколько доменов / несколько поддоменов в Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, kotlin

Возможно ли средствами Spring (https://spring.io/projects) сделать так, чтобы разные домены / поддомены, подключенные к одному ip (в моем случае к одному серверу), обрабатывались разными слушателями (портами / контроллерами). Искал информацию по этой теме, нашел пару костылей, которые частично работают, но это костыли.

Comment: Средствами **spring** нельзя. Spring - это фреймворк для внедрения зависимостей, сетевые запросы он сам не обрабатывает.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а какие есть нормальные способы организовать это?

Comment: Прежде всего надо определиться, что же вам надо организовать. У вас Spring MVC? Spring Webflow? Что-то ещё? Работает в web-контейнере встроенного Jetty? Развёрнуто в Tomcat? В glassfish? Wildfly?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev просто MVC. По дефолту вроде Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу, необходимо в одном экземпляре web-приложения динамически выбирать контроллер в зависимости от запрошенного домена. Не знаю зачем такое нужно, выглядит само по себе как костыль, но сделать можно.

Spring MVC для маппинга url-адресов использует реализации интерфейса [HandlerMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html). Обычно `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`. Его можно подменить:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping;

import com.example.SomeController;

@Component
public class DomainHandler extends AbstractHandlerMapping {
    @Autowired
    private ListableBeanFactory listableBeanFactory;

    private Map<String, Object> controllers;

    @PostConstruct
    private void loadControllers() {
        controllers = listableBeanFactory.getBeansWithAnnotation(Controller.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getHandlerInternal(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        String domainName = request.getServerName();
        switch (domainName) {
            case "example.com":
                return controllers.get("exampleController");
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Эх, в том то и дело, что это костыль. Я тут прочитал про tomcat, насколько я понял, можно преобразовать /somepage в /sub[0-99]/somepage, где sub[0-99] - поддомен(ы). И просто роутить поддомен как часть пути. Читаю про RewriteRule, если это не то, останови меня.

Comment: Правильно понял вашу задачу?
Вам необходимо чтобы при запросе из интернета http://abc.foo.bar/ отрабатывал http://localhost:8080/abc/, а при запросе http://xyz.foo.bar/ отрабатывал http://localhost:8080/xyz/

Comment: @АлексейПересторонин ага, наверное, можно использовать rewrite valve на заголовок HTTP_HOST.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev допустим, есть `dev.com` и `prod.com` сервера, нужно обработать оба. Сначала мы меняем `HTTP_HOST` на `site.com`, затем делаем `RewriteRule`, преобразующий `/example` в `/site.com/example`. Любые домены, любые поддомены, главное regexp правильно составить.

Comment: @АлександрПоташев да, правильно. Но еще и для разных доменов.